# restore database in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to restore my database using this code and it doesn't work

```
$server_name   = "localhost";
$username      = "root";
$password      = "admin";
$database_name = "uvatravelclone";
$file = basename($_POST["file_open"]);
//$cmd = "mysql -h {$server_name} -u {$username} -p{$password} {$database_name} $file";
$cmd = "mysql -e {$file}";
if (exec($cmd) == true){
   echo "succes";
}
else{
   echo " error";
}
```

i need to get the file name or file path of the data because i'm using

```
<input type=file>
```

to open the file.

Comment: RTFM? http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php And note that your code is opening your system to a **COMPLETE** remote compromise, by directly passing user input into to a shell.

Comment: The argument to `mysql -e` is a SQL command, not a filename. If you want to get input from a file, you need to redirect input with `< filename`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `<input type="file" name="file_open">`, the information about the uploaded file is put in `$_FILES`, not `$_POST`. The file contents are put into a temporary file, and `$_FILES['file_open']['tmp_name']` contains the pathname to this temporary file. You can then redirect this to the `mysql` command, using `< filename` for shell input redirection.

```
$server_name   = "localhost";
$username      = "root";
$password      = "admin";
$database_name = "uvatravelclone";
$file = $_FILES['file_open']['tmp_name']
$cmd = "mysql -h {$server_name} -u {$username} -p{$password} {$database_name} < $file";
if (exec($cmd)){
   echo "success";
}
else{
   echo " error";
}
```

Note that the return value of `exec()` is the last line of output of the command, not a true/false value that indicates success.

Comment: thank you sir it works iand i just add file path of mysql

Comment: `$_FILE`? That should be `$_FILES`, *n'est-ce pas?* ;-)

Comment: You've discovered my secret, I don't do lots of file upload programming :)

Answer (score 3):

Things to be known, when you have a `type=file` in your HTML Form, its necessary to use `method="post"` and `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

**Example**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="filename" />
<button>Upload Now</button> 
</form>
```

**Render Using PHP**

```
<?php
$getFile  = $_FILES["filename"];
var_dump($getFile); //Prints uploaded file details

//Use copy or move_uploaded_file to store the uploaded file on server
//its always better to use move_uploaded_file for the purpose.
?>
```

Know more it in this link http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp.

Comment: Linking to the core PHP docs, which often have very helpful observations and examples in the comments, is often way better than some third party site, especially w3schools.

Comment: but I'm trying to restore my database not actually open the file. that is if my understanding is correct

Comment: procedure goes same for every kind of file, while you use `type=file`

Comment: `$_FILE` That should be `$_FILES` and missing a parameter. You even had the example on the W3 link of yours.

Comment: Ha ha ha.. Yup you are right, @Fredii.. It's a typo. :)

Answer (score 1):

+1 to Barmar's answer, but here's another tip: `exec()` can fetch the exit status of the command you execute, and this is a more accurate indicator of success or failure.

Traditionally, when a command has an exit status of 0 it means success, and any nonzero value means some error.

```
exec($cmd, $output, $exitStatus);
if (0 == $exitStatus)){
   echo "success";
}
else{
   echo " error";
}
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php